# Лишний результат при поиске пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

http://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/alltime/ru-stackoverflow вот тут, при поиске пользователя текущий пользователь не исчезает в списке результатов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полагаю, «так задумано». Что плохого в том, что всегда видишь свою репутацию и место в топах, и можешь сравнивать себя с другими участниками? Даже если репутация серьёзно различается, можно быстро сравнить, сколько усилий нужно приложить, чтобы подняться на энное количество мест.

Comment: Это же специальная страница для замеряшек. Собственная карточка там закреплена, чтобы можно было сравнивать.